# Ansible error "'dict object' has no attribute u'xxxxxxxx.dev'??

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible and vagrant, I am getting this error message when I try to run vagrant provision

```
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute u'xxxxxxxx.dev'"}
```

I think it is an error in this below file and i have tried to change format but it is not working

```
wordpress_sites:
  xxxxx.com.in:
    site_hosts:
      - xxxxx.dev
    local_path: ../site 
    site_install: true
    site_title: Xxxxx
    admin_user: admin
    # admin_password: (defined in group_vars/development/vault.yml)
    admin_email: xxxxx@xxxxxx.dev
    initial_permalink_structure: /%postname%/ # applied only at time of WP install and when `site_install: true`
    multisite:
      enabled: false
      subdomains: false
    ssl:
      enabled: false
    cache:
      enabled: false
      duration: 30s
    env:
      disable_wp_cron: true
      wp_home: http://xxxxxx.dev
      wp_siteurl: http://xxxxxx.dev/wp
      wp_env: development
      db_name: xxxxxx
      db_user: xxxxxx
      # db_password: (defined in group_vars/development/vault.yml)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the task(s) where it's failing?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - TASK [wordpress-setup : Create/assign database user to db and grant permissions] ***  -  Thank you response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://discourse.roots.io/t/setting-up-vagrant-box-error-dict-object-has-no-attribute-site-hosts-failed-true/4317/6?u=anudeep_g_i) help me

I have changed `'example.com'` to `'xxxxx.com.in'` in - `'group_vars/development/vault.yml'`

Now it working